# Using Proxy Service for Static IP

Tags: proxy, ip

My app runs in the cloud (AWS Elastic Beanstalk). The app uses an external web service which allows calls only from known IP addresses (I would provide them my IP address so that they can add it to the allowed IP list). The environment my app is running in (AWS Elastic Beanstalk) does not use fixed static IP addresses.

Is there a free (or paid) service that acts as a proxy and has known IP addresses so that my app can go through it to call the web service?

Note: This question is a general one and not necessarily specific to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It applies to any environment where there is no static IP assigned to the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a t1.micro instance, bind a static IP to it and run a proxy server (such as Squid/Varnish/Nginx or even Apache) on top of it